# Сортировка трехмерного массива PHP

Tags: php

Задача в общем простая надо просто волшебный пендель:

```
Array
(
    [2010] => Array
        (
            [События] => Array
                (
                    [22 июня - День памяти павших] => 5844019782278600417
                    [Юбилей лагеря - 55 лет] => 5844019550003234209
                    [Танцевальный марафон] => 5844018915767536433
                    [Вокальный конкурс] => 5844018195572988705
                    [Концерт] => 5844020074698918273
                )

        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [Вожатые] => Array
                (
                    [Фото вожатых] => 5844017830159484209
                )

            [События] => Array
                (
                    [Новый год] => 5844016823516991345
                )

        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [Кружки] => Array
                (
                    [Различные кружки] => 5844020920369473777
                    [Секции] => 5844021521354443873
                )

        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [Кружки] => Array
                (
                    [Секции зима] => 5841466816236498241
                )

            [События] => Array
                (
                    [Конкурс талантов зима] => 5841470410339092001
                    [Квн зима] => 5841470972023339409
                )

            [Лагерь] => Array
                (
                    [Зимняя смена] => 5841471421106664321
                    [Зимние фото часть 2] => 5841447735046599777
                )

        )

)
```

Отсортировать по годам в порядке убывания по остальному по алфавиту.
т.е. вот так:

```
Array
(
    [2013] => Array
        (
            [Кружки] => Array
                (
                    [Секции зима] => 5841466816236498241
                )

            [Лагерь] => Array
                (
                    [Зимние фото часть 2] => 5841447735046599777
                    [Зимняя смена] => 5841471421106664321
                )

            [События] => Array
                (
                    [Квн зима] => 5841470972023339409
                    [Конкурс талантов зима] => 5841470410339092001
                )

        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [Кружки] => Array
                (
                    [Различные кружки] => 5844020920369473777
                    [Секции] => 5844021521354443873
                )

        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [Вожатые] => Array
                (
                    [Фото вожатых] => 5844017830159484209
                )

            [События] => Array
                (
                    [Новый год] => 5844016823516991345
                )

        )

    [2010] => Array
        (
            [События] => Array
                (
                    [22 июня - День памяти павших] => 5844019782278600417
                    [Вокальный конкурс] => 5844018195572988705
                    [Концерт] => 5844020074698918273
                    [Танцевальный марафон] => 5844018915767536433
                    [Юбилей лагеря - 55 лет] => 5844019550003234209
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: приведите пример массива, который хотите получить

Comment: обновил вопрос

Comment: разобрася хватает ksort